# Divide text from richtext box to other textbox depending the clasification in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, textbox, richtextbox

i hope someone can help me. it would me life saving.

so let me tell you, for a school proyect i have to make a microcontroller pic16f877a send data to an aplication on a computer and then send the data to a database that is going to be shown in charts on a website that i have to make.

the thing is that im stuck on how to seperate the data from a rich textbox and send it to another text box.

for example. here is a snapshot

[image: main interface]

so the data that is being obtained by the pic via serial port is being displayed in the rich textbox.

so now what i want to do is. when the button "obtener" that is under the normal textbox is clicked. the data from the richtextbox gets sorted and added to the textbox depending on what it says.

for exmple, if in the first line of the rich textbox it says "Temperatura" it should go to the textbox with the tags that says temperatura.

and the same to the other data. where it says "humedad" it should go to the normaltextbox where it has the tag "humedad."

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have all data in textBox seperated like these on the picture,
you need just to properly process the string:

```
        Dictionary<string, int> values = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        string textBoxString = textBoxName.Text;

        // Splits text into array of seperate lines
        List<string> split = s.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < split.Count; i++)
        {

            // removes free spaces
            split[i] = split[i].Replace(" ", String.Empty);


            // splits one line into pair of property name (example: temperature) and it's value after seperator ":"
            string[] keyPair = split[i].Split(':'); 

            // adds property name as dictionary's key and value as dictionary's value
            values.Add(keyPair[0], int.Parse(keyPair[1])); 
        }
```

In dictionary you have property name and it's value so you can now create for example switch statement in which you assign dictionary value to proper variable and then you can bind text boxes where you want to show values to variables you've just assigned